# How to write Partial Join Query in a Select Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to write a Join within a table to return not matching partial column value record.

```
Id    PersonName     FileId    FileName

36   Kenneth Park   1002    Kenneth H. Park 
36   Kenneth Park   1002    Kenneth H. Park 
29   Margaret That  1008    Robert Strauss
```

Expected Result

```
Id    PersonName     FileId    FileName
29   Margaret That   1008   Robert Strauss
```

Comment: What is a "not matching partial column value record"?

Comment: I will have to correct those Not Matching records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is a bit strange because there are exact duplicates.  If you want the rows that are not exact duplicates, you need to use `group by`, not `join` (unless you have other columns that can distinguish the rows):

```
select id, PersonName, FileId, FileName
from t
group by id, PersonName, FileId, FileName
having count(*) = 1;
```